# Messages app on macOS Mojave (10.14.6) constantly giving me the spinning pinwheel - Mac Pro 4.1 with 64 GBs of RAM

Tags: mojave, messages

My Mac Pro 4.1 has very good specs for its time: 64 GBs of RAM, 500 GB SSD, 3.33 GHz 6-core Intel Xeon, etc. No resource contention at all. However, I get the "beachball" almost every time I use the Messages app. All other programs seem fine. Plenty of disk-space on the machine. GPU is supported for Mojave: Radeon RX 560 2GB

I found this post, but I only have 2 accounts: iCloud & Gmail.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7724763

How can I troubleshoot and fix this?

Update: this may have helped, but it's a bit early to say for sure (from the apple.com post linked above):

> In the Contacts App > Preferences > Accounts make sure only one account is being used (preferably the one being used by the iPhone and other iOS devices).

Comment: Did you put a Metal 2 GPU in it & flash it to 5,1 or is it using a hack to run Mojave?

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, good question, thanks. No hack, it is using a proper "metal" GPU: Radeon RX 560 2 GB. I'll update the post to reflect this.